# sending action to previosu view when using dismissModalViewController iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am using presentModalViewController to display a view which allows the user to modify data that is being displayed in the first view. After the user has updated the data, I would like to send [tableView reloadData] to the first view.

Is that possible? Or is there a method I can create in the first view that gets called when the modalView is dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should fit perfectly for your needs

[Method for when the modal view has been dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193535/method-for-when-the-modal-view-has-been-dismissed)

EDIT: syntax errors :)

Comment: I tried this and I got this error. Am I doing it wrong? I added a method to the parent view called it "reloadData" then called this in viewWillDisappear: [self.parentViewController reloadData]; -[UITabBarController reloadData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4a215e0'