# Parent View Controller and Model View Controller dismissal detection not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController called `ShowListViewController` that uses a Modal View Controller to push another view onto the stack:

```
AddShowViewController *addShowViewController = [[AddShowViewController alloc] init];
[addShowViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentModalViewController:addShowViewController animated:YES];
```

I would then like to call my method populateTableData of the `ShowListViewController` class when the `addShowViewController` disappears.

I would think that the [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193535/method-for-when-the-modal-view-has-been-dismissed) would work, but it doesn't. My method `populateTableData` is not detected as an optional method to use.

Essentially my questions is: **How do I detect when a Modal View Controller disappears so as to call a method within the class that pushed it on the stack?**

Comment: When tagging questions about Cocoa Touch on iOS (iPhone, iPad), use the ‘cocoa-touch’ tag. The ‘cocoa’ tag is for questions about Cocoa on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it appears that in Apple's template for `Utility App's` they ignore what the docs for [UIViewController][1] say and actually go out of their way to call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` from the `UIViewController` that pushed the modal view onto screen.

The basic idea in your case will be

1. Define a protocol for `AddShowViewControllerDelegate`
2. Make `ShowListViewController` implement this protocol
3. Call a method on the delegate to ask it to dimiss the modal view controller

For a full example just create a new project with `Utility` template and look at the source for `FlipsideViewController` and `MainViewController`

Here is an example adapted for your needs:

**AddShowViewController.h**

```
@class AddShowViewController;

@protocol AddShowViewControllerDelegate
- (void)addShowViewControllerDidFinish:(AddShowViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface AddShowViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AddShowViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

**AddShowViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate addShowViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}
```

**ShowListViewController.h**

```
@interface ShowListViewController : UIViewController <AddShowViewControllerDelegate>
{   
    ...
}
```

**ShowListViewController.m**

```
- (void)addShowViewControllerDidFinish:(AddShowViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self populateTableData];
}
```

Comment: So just to be clear, according to my example I would stick this in `showListViewController` i.e. the parent view controller and then call  `populateTable` within it?

Comment: I also don't get the `[self ShowListViewController]` bit.

Comment: Sorry I'm using an iPad and copied the wrong thing see updated

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Paul.s, but this does absolutely nothing. Any other ideas or advice? Thanks again.

Comment: How are you dismissing the controller?

Comment: In `addShowViewController` I am using `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Sorry I just tried this and it does not work the way the documentation suggests. Perhaps instead of calling `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` you could call `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. The docs states that `The parent view controller is responsible for dismissing the modal view controller...` therefore this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a best solution, but can do what you want at this time.

In your showlistcontroller add an instance variable like

```
BOOL pushedView;
@implementation ShowListViewController
```

and before you do the modal presentation set its values as YES like

```
pushedView = YES;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:popView animated:YES];
```

in the viewWillAppear of ShowListViewController you can detect whether it is appearing because pop getting dismissed or not like

```
if (pushedView) {
    NSLog(@"Do things you would like to on pop dismissal");
    pushedView = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like something like this.

You make a delegate inside ur modalVC like this:

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didDismissModalView;

@end
```

and implement it in your MainVC like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <ModalViewDelegate>
{
```

Then u will make a delegate property in your modalVC like this:

```
    @interface ModalShizzle : UIViewController
    {
        id<ModalViewDelegate> dismissDelegate;
    }
```

You set the dismissDelegate of your ModalVC to your MainVC and then you make the delegate method. Before you dismiss it however you will call the ModalVC to do one last thing. (which is populate your table). You will call for the data inside your MainVC and then do whatever you feel like it, just before you dismissed your modalVC.

```
-(void)didDismissModalView
{
    //call ModalVC data here...
    //then do something with that data. set it to a property inside this MainVC or call a method with it.
    //method/data from modalVC is called here and now u can safely dismiss modalVC
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope it helps ;)